# appending tkinter inputs to csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter

My first code experience (try not to laugh *too* much). I'm trying to write barcode entries  (as an HID, just like a keyboard) to a csv file - although the function to display a label of the input data works, when i look at the csv file, I'm unable to capture the inputs.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import * 
import csv
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv("new.csv")
data = []

dt = datetime.now()
dt_string = dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

root = Tk()
root.title ("Robot Interface")
root.geometry ("600x300")
root.configure(background="sky blue")


def acknowledge(event):
    acknowledge_label = Label(root, 
        text=" Data Logged \n " + dt_string 
        + "\n Operator ~ " + textBoxName.get()
        + "\n Item ~ "+ textBoxJob.get() 
        + "\n Ser' No' ~ "+ textBoxSN.get() 
        + "\n Command Sent To Robot", 
        bg="sky blue", fg="red", anchor="e", justify=LEFT)
    acknowledge_label.place(x=390, y=20),
    
def log():
    val1 = textBoxName.get()
    val2 = textBoxJob.get()
    val3 = textBoxSN.get()
    data = [val1, val2, val3, dt_string]
    print(data)
    
    
    #textBoxName.delete(0, END)
    #textBoxJob.delete(0, END)
    #textBoxSN.delete(0, END)
   


#NAME
labelName = Label(root, text = "Name:", bg="sky blue")
labelName.place(x=10,y=20)

textBoxName = Entry (root, width=30, borderwidth=2)
textBoxName.place(x=80, y=20)
textBoxName.focus_set()

#JOB ID
labelJob = Label(root, text = "Job ID:", bg="sky blue")
labelJob.place(x=10, y=70)

textBoxJob = Entry (root, width=30, borderwidth=2)
textBoxJob.place(x=80, y=70)

#SERIAL NUMBER
labelSN = Label(root, text = "Ser No.", bg="sky blue")
labelSN.place(x=10, y=120)

textBoxSN = Entry (root, width=30, borderwidth=2)
textBoxSN.place(x=80, y=120)



#SUBMIT
ButtonSubmit = Button(root, text="SUBMIT", command=acknowledge)
ButtonSubmit.bind("<Return>", acknowledge)
ButtonSubmit.bind("<Button-1>", acknowledge)

ButtonSubmit.place(x=80, y=170)

df.to_csv('new.csv',index=False)
newrow=(dt_string, log,"pass")


with open('new.csv', 'a') as appendobj:
    append = csv.writer(appendobj)
    append.writerow (newrow)
textBoxName 

#CONFIG
ButtonConfig = Button(root, text="Config Page")
ButtonConfig.place(x=80, y=240)

root.mainloop()
```

The output:

date, header1, header2, header3

16/04/21 00:43:43,**<function log at 0x7f4c75ca3790>**,pass

---

How can I turn the  message into the input data please?
Oh, and any other ideas for improvement welcome too!

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you need our help with? _"I'm unable to capture the inputs."_: Why is that?

Comment: If, for example, I entered x, y and z values into each of the tkinter text boxes, the acknowledge function correctly displays these values in the acknowledge_label in the GUI. However, i want to also post the text box inputs to a csv file too. If I were to then open the csv file, instead of seeing 'x', 'y', and 'z' in the columns , I see "<function log at 0x7f4c75ca3790>, " - hope that makes my request a little more clear...sorry it was poorly written

Comment: `def log():` is what `log` is. And that is what it is showing. What is your expected output.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is append  the entries in the tkinter text boxes to the last row a csv file. so, in this example x, y & z

Comment: Try using: `newrow=(dt_string, textBoxName.get(),"pass")` instead of what's there originally.

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a go and reply back. Son has hijacked my pc for now (replying from phone)

Comment: tried your suggestion but the csv file now shows: 17/04/21 00:14:05,,pass

Comment: that is, the date/time, a double comma (nothing in between) then the string 'pass'

Comment: Nothing in between means, your entry box is empty, put all those inside a function and call the function.